# Equivalence result on recursive enumerable sets

Tags: recursion, computability

I am reading the book of Robert Soare for recursive enumerable sets and degrees. There is the so called listing theorem, which stands that a set A is recursive enumerable if and only if A is not empty or A is the range of a total recursive function. In the proof of the $ \Rightarrow $ implication, the function is defined as $$ 
f(<s, x>) = 
    \begin{cases} 
        x & if \ x \in W_{e, s+1} - W_{e, s} \\
        a & otherwise 
    \end{cases}
$$
where $<a, t>$ is the least integer such that $ a \in W_{e, t}$

The theorem also says that $f$ can be found uniformly, i.e., $ \exists \psi $ such that it is p.r., $ \lambda y \psi(e, y) $ is total, and $ W_{e} = \{ \psi(e, y) | y \in \omega \} $

The question is, why is not valid a function defined as $ f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  x & if x \in A \\
  a & otherwise 
\end{cases}
$

I mean, if computing the conditions on the first definition for $f$ is r.e. it should also be for the second one. And apparently, the $ \psi $ function can be defined as well.

I think that it can not be as easy as I think, so there should be some missconception for my part.

Comment: Your proposed $f$ isn't recursive. To compute $f(x)$, you need to know whether $x\in A$ or not. If $A$ isn't recursive, then you won't be able to compute (recursively) whether $x\in A$.

Comment: Okey, that makes sense, but the argument is not valid for those $ W_{e, s} $? I mean, $ A = W_{e} $ so that is the only difference I can see

Comment: $W_{e,s}$ is computable (from $e$ and $s$). The point is that checking whether $z\in W_{e,s}$ only requires going through the first $s$ steps of producing $W_e$, so it can be done by a finite computation.  (In contrast,  checking whether $z\in W_e$ requires going through all, possibly infinitely many, steps of producing $W_e$.) In other words, when trying to compute whether $z\in W_e$ you'll never be certain that $z$ won't get into $W_e$ at a later step of the computation. With $z\in W_{e,s}$, you don't have that problem; you'll know after $s+1$ steps.

Comment: Adding to @AndreasBlass's comment, in fact $W_{e,s}$ is **uniformly** computable in $e$ and $s$: there is a total computable function $f(a,b,c)$ such that for all $a,b,c$ we have $$f(a,b,c)=1\iff a\in W_{b,c}.$$